# Phone number validation function in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, character

I'm trying to create a part of a program in which I need to verify if the input string is a valid phone number or not.

A valid phone number may contain digits and non-digit characters of '`+`', '`-`', '`(`', '`)`'. There should be at least one digit in a phone number (order & length does not matter). Thus all other characters and of course letters are invalid. I know how to check if a single character/symbol is inside a string or not, but now there are 26 x 2 (lower & upper case) + other invalid symbols, I don't think it's very logical to check if there are each of these individual invalid characters inside the string.

Is there a C function (maybe not 1 function but a few combined) that can accommodate for this? Or is there another way to do it?

Example of how it will go like:

```
char aString[50];
scanf("%s", aString);
//checks if aString is valid or not
```

Comment: [`strspn()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) checks the length of the initial part of string composed only of some characters, so you can do `len = strspn(aString, "0123456789()+-"); if (len == strlen(aString)) /* ok */;` for a first basic check.

Comment: The functions (macros) from `<ctype.h>` may be of some use, but some of the more esoteric functions from `<string.h>` are more likely to be of help.  The functions in [§7.24.5 Search functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5) such as `strcspn()`, `strspn()` and `strpbrk()` are probably helpful.  Ultimately, you're going to want to impose some order on the characters: `+` at the start (only) and followed by a digit; `(` before `)` (but if `(` is present, so is `)`); no nested parentheses; `(` followed by a digit; `)` preceded by digit; `-` separating two digits — etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
  
int checkphone(char *s)
{
        char *i, *valid_chars = "01234567890+-()";
        int has_at_least_one_digit = 0;

        for(; *s && (i = strchr(valid_chars, *s)); s++)
                has_at_least_one_digit |= (i < valid_chars + 10);

        return (*s == '\0') && has_at_least_one_digit;
}
  
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i;
  
        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
                printf("Parameter '%s' %s a phone number.\n",
                        argv[i],
                        checkphone(argv[i]) ? "is" : "isn't");

        exit(0);
}
```

Run this program with:

```
gcc -Wall -o t t.c && ./t +34-478-232-434 892754 343-34 potato +3+3+3 +++ +-+- -43
Parameter '+34-478-232-434' is a phone number.
Parameter '892754' is a phone number.
Parameter '343-34' is a phone number.
Parameter 'potato' isn't a phone number.
Parameter '+3+3+3' is a phone number.
Parameter '+++' isn't a phone number.
Parameter '+-+-' isn't a phone number.
Parameter '-43' is a phone number.
```

Comment: Using `i` as a `char *` (indeed, using it as almost anything except some variant of an integer type) is aconventional — not wrong, but unusual.  Using `p` or `s` would be more orthodox.